# How to count same values in different cell as 1 instead of increase by 1 by 1 sql

Tags: sql

I'm trying to count the Total Number of Supervisors for each branch according to branch ID (B001, B002, B003). I'm trying to get the result like 'Sandy' counted as 1 and 'Mandy' counted as another (total 2 supervisors for B001) but after i executed, the result showed 3 (Sandy counted separately as 2 different values instead of 1). so, what should i do to make total number of supervisor in B001 branch becomes 2.

[there are 3 B001 in that table, but the supervisors are only sandy and mandy which Supervisor Sandy is repeated. The result showed there are 3 supervisors after i executed, so how can i make it to 2?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK7OS.png)

results shown:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcA69.png)

`SELECT Staff.BranchID,Branch.Manager AS ManagerName,
    COUNT (staff.Supervisor) AS TotalNumberofSupervisor
    FROM Staff INNER JOIN Branch ON Branch.BranchID = Staff.BranchID
    GROUP BY Staff.BranchID,Branch.Manager`

Comment: Can you add the relevant rows / columns from the STAFF and BRANCH tables? Would make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "COUNT (distinct(staff.Supervisor))" instead of 
"COUNT (staff.Supervisor)" will help